PowerApps: Column charts using choice field?
I have an intake SharePoint list where a form is submitted using PowerApps. I'm building a dashboard view within that PowerApp for users to see real-time updates to their existing submissions. There should be a filter using: Filter(Submitter.Email = User().Email) on the charts in the dashboard screen.
The SharePoint list has a multi-select SharePoint choice field called "Status". In PowerApp, I'm trying to show a column chart with each Status as a bar with the count of requests within each Status.
Use Case: If a user has submitted 5 total requests, 2 are in "Awaiting manager review" status, and the other 3 are in "Manager approved". For example, I want to show a column chart with Statuses count as 2 and 3 with the corresponding status choices. If we need to show all the other bars as zero, that's fine. It'd be great to only show the bars that have a value.
I've tried a variety of codes including AddColumns, GroupBy, Distinct, Count, and CountRows and every time I try to use any function it errors.
My Status column is named "Status" and the SharePoint list is called 'DCXM Intake'.

If the Status column is a choice column that does not allow multiple selections, then you first need to extract the value from that choice (using the AddColumns function), before you can group it (you can only group on columns of scalar types, which is not the case of a Choice column):
AddColumns(
    GroupBy(
        AddColumns('DCXM Intake', StatusValue, Status.Value),
        StatusValue,
        ByStatus
    ),
    Count,
    CountRows(ByStatus)
)

If the Status column allows multiple selections, then you first need to "flatten" it; after that you can group based on the value. The filter below is necessary if you don't want any records that don't have any selections; if that's ok, then you can omit it.
AddColumns(
    GroupBy(
        Filter(
            Ungroup('DCXM Intake', Status),
            Not IsBlank(Value)
        ),
        Value,
        ByStatus),
    Count,
    CountRows(ByStatus)
)

